# SimpleSchema: Depending values instead of optional values

Tags: javascript, meteor, simple-schema

This is how my SimpleSchema validation looks like:

```
validate: new SimpleSchema({
    type: { type: String, allowedValues: ['start', 'stop'] },
    _id : { type: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id, optional: true },
    item: { type: String, optional: true }
}).validator()
```

But it is not exactly what I am needing:

If `type` is *start*, there must be a `item` value and if `type` is *stop* there must be an `_id` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by changing your code like below

```
validate: new SimpleSchema({
  type: { type: String, allowedValues: ['start', 'stop'] },
  _id : { 
    type: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id, 
    optional: true,
    custom: function () {
      if (this.field('type').value == 'stop') {
        return SimpleSchema.ErrorTypes.REQUIRED
      }
    } 
  },
  item: { 
    type: String, 
    optional: true,
    custom: function () {
      if (this.field('type').value == 'start') {
        if(!this.isSet || this.value === null || this.value === "") {
          return SimpleSchema.ErrorTypes.REQUIRED
        }
      }
    }
  }
}).validator()
```

If you use **atmosphere package** of SimpleSchema you can replace `return SimpleSchema.ErrorTypes.REQUIRED` with `return 'required'`. I tested above code only using **NPM package** and both versions worked fine.

This is a very basic implementation of this functionality. SimpleSchema even allows to conditionally require field depending on the performed operation(insert, update).

You can read more about it in the docs

- If you use old atmosphere package
  https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#make-a-field-conditionally-required
- If  you use new NPM package https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema#make-a-field-conditionally-required

Comment: For me it is not working. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943512/simpleschema-conditionally-required-field-is-not-working

Comment: @user3142695 you are right. I found the error and will update answer in minutes.