# SimpleSchema: Conditionally required field is not working

Tags: javascript, meteor, simple-schema

This is how I'm doing a validation using SimpleSchema with a *conditionally* required field (`module`). So this should only be required if `type` has the value 'start'

**client**

```
const   module = 'articles',
        _id = 'bmphCpyHZLhTc74Zp'

console.log(module, _id)
// returns as expected 'articles' and 'bmphCpyHZLhTc74Zp'

example.call(
    {
        type  : 'start',
        module: module,
        _id   : _id
    },
    (error, result) => {
        if (error)  console.log(error)
    }
)
```

**server**

```
example = new ValidatedMethod({
    name    : 'example',
    validate: new SimpleSchema({
        _id : { type: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id },
        type: {
            type         : String,
            allowedValues: ['start', 'stop'] },
        module: {
            type         : String,
            optional     : true,
            allowedValues: ['articles'],
            custom       : function() {
                if (this.field('type').value === 'start') return 'required'
                return null
            }
        }
    }).validator(),

    run({ type, _id, module }) {
        console.log(_id, module)
    }
})
```

But I do get the error `"validation-error"` with reason `"Module is required"`.

I do not understand that, as you can see `module` has a value at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation error occurs because you don't check if module contains any value(my answer to your previous question contained error), so every time when `type` value equals `start` the method throw error about a required field. It don't even check if `module` field has any value. I post your fixed code.

```
example = new ValidatedMethod({
  name    : 'example',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    _id : { type: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id },
    type: {
      type: String,
      allowedValues: ['start', 'stop'] 
    },
    module: {
      type: String,
      optional: true,
      allowedValues: ['articles'],
      custom: function() {
        if (this.field('type').value === 'start') {
          if(!this.isSet || this.value === null || this.value === "") {
            return 'required'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }).validator(),
  run({ type, _id, module }) {
    console.log(_id, module)
  }
})
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to do `if (!this.isSet || !this.value)`?

Comment: Yes using `if (!this.isSet || !this.value)` will be enough. Anyway, I will leave my answer as it is, so people will get a better understanding.